# How to build the following visual

Tags: wpf

I am not a real designer and I would like to know if anyone have an idea how can I build the following visual  :

[image]

The idea is to get 2 rings where inside I will draw secific number of pie represented as "Interactive shape or button". Base on the number of shape, they should cover the whole circle.

In addition to that, I need to be able to interact with each pie shape, and inside and oustide edge of those shape should be a perfect arc based on the circle diameter.

As I am not a perfect designer, how can I represent this visual ?
I was thinking of using a custom panel but then how to draw each panel shape in order that they gets perfect inside and ouside arc and offer interactivity with each of them ?

Thanks for your help
 I would appreciate samples as well

Comment: @user930203 Isn't there a way in WPF to perform boolean operations on Geometry objects? I seem to remember that there is. If so - taking a circle, then a smaller circle, subtracting one from the other will give you your circular outline (with a hole). Then bisecting this with triangles will give you the segments. Not posting as answer as I haven't tested / confirmed this as a strategy, but nevertheless, might be helpful to you. Regards,

Comment: @Dr.AndrewBurnett-Thompson I believe you are right in this. I have seem some image clipping done in WPF using `Geometry` objects. There is some information over on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.clip.aspx) for it.

Comment: @SamuelSlade in a previous life, far far away I did a lot of low-level Geometry hacking in WPF. For the original questionner - a tool you may consider using to create complex UI is Expression Blend. Also I have used successfully Inkscape (with SVG) and exported my created geometry to Xaml.

Comment: @Dr.AndrewBurnett-Thompson I would also second the use of Expression Blend.

Comment: @Dr.Andrew what do you mean by "Then bisecting this with triangles"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theres actually a [Silverlight](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/creating-ui/charting-controls/silverlight-toolkit-pie-chart) tutorial on making something exactly like this.

If you didnt want to use that, you could always do it in javascript. Here's an example using [Rapheal js](http://raphaeljs.com/pie.html)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend looking into [WPF Geometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751808.aspx) and how you can create custom controls (such as the [Circular Gauge Custom Control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/circulargaugecontrol.aspx) over on CodeProject) using said Geometry.

I've never created a control quite like what your suggesting, but I would image you would define some form of area that can contain children and style it so that it forms the circular shape you want. Then, adding interactive regions should be as simple as adding controls to standard containers.

Comment: but in that cas i use the Geometry , what will be the parent visual of the goemerty ? custom panels ? I really do not see how to reach my goal may be I am blind

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [link](http://alexpkent.wordpress.com/2012/10/04/wpf-radial-context-menu-pie-menu/) to a "generic radial panel that can be used to host any items" which subclasses `Panel`.